# jsGgrid campo personalizado

Tags: javascript, lib

Tenho o seguinte script para montar uma tabela com jsGrid

```
var montaGridPacientes = function (data) {
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: "90%",
        width: "100%",

        filtering: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

        data: data,



        fields: [
            { name: "CPF", type: "text", width: 50 },
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, title: "Nome" },
            { name: "DateOfBirth", type: "date", width: 60, title: "Nascimento" }

        ]
    });
    loading(false);
};
```

E me vem o seguinte resultado

[image: Ignorem a cor cinza das letras]

O campo de nascimento esta com esse padrao da data aceita pelo JSON:
`/Date(385441200000-0300)/`

Como eu apenas passo o meu JSON diretamente apra o script em: `data: data,`

Como colocar uma modificação neste campo para personaliza-lo  e converter essa data em um date do tipo `01/01/2017`

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado adicionando o itemTemplate:

```
  $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        height: "90%",
        width: "100%",

        filtering: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        pageButtonCount: 5,

        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

        data: data,



        fields: [
            { name: "Cpf", type: "text", width: 50 },
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, title: "Nome" },
            {
                name: "DateOfBirth", type: "date", width: 60, title: "Nascimento",
                itemTemplate: function (value) {
                    return new moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            } }

        ]
    });
```